# Unable to pass a variable in with_dict

Tags: ansible

Im trying to pass a variable in a with_dict loop taken from the first play of my playbook to the second play of that playbook(where the with_dict is executed).

Here is my dictonary:

```
ws:
  datasources:
    password: example
```

and here is the loop im trying to run:

```
    - replace:
    path: /usr/local/example/example
    regexp: '!password_variable!'
    replace: "{{ item.value.password }}"
  with_dict: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['platform'] }}"
```

What i want to happen is i am able to pass "ws" as the platform variable so i have the ability to select between multiple platform passwords. This works fine if I hardcore "ws" under with_dict.

Edit: forgot to say that the error I get is "with_dict expects a dict". 
This leads me to believe that the variable is being picked up but it does not like it for some reason.

Comment: What is the relation between platform and your dictionary key?

Comment: i want platform to equal "ws" in the given example.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Pass a variable ... from the first play of my playbook to the second play ..."*

A: Use `hostvars`. The [scope of hostvars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/playbooks_variables.html#variable-scopes) is the host. For example declare the variable with `set_fact`.

---

Examples of the scope

**Play**: each play and contained structures, vars entries, include_vars, role defaults and vars.

Example 1. The variable `my_var1` defined in `vars` of the first play **is not defined** in the next play

```
- name: Play 1
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_var1: Hello world!
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_var1

- name: Play 2
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_var1
```

gives

```
PLAY [Play 1] ***********

TASK [debug] ************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_var1": "Hello world!"
}

PLAY [Play 2] ***********

TASK [debug] ************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_var1": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Example 2. The variable `my_var2` defined in `vars_prompt` of the first play **is also not defined** in the next play

```
- name: Play 3
  hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: my_var2
      prompt: "What is the value of my_var2?"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_var2

- name: Play 4
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_var2
```

gives

```
What is the value of my_var2?: 

PLAY [Play 3] ***********

TASK [debug] ************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_var2": "Hello world!"
}

PLAY [Play 4] ***********

TASK [debug] ************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_var2": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

**Host**: variables directly associated to a host, like inventory, facts or registered task outputs.

Example 3. The variable `my_var3` defined in `facts` of the first play **is defined** in the next play

```
- name: Play 5
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_var3: Hello world!
    - debug:
        var: my_var3

- name: Play 6
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_var3
```

gives

```
PLAY [Play 5] *************

TASK [set_fact] ***********
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_var3": "Hello world!"
}

PLAY [Play 6] *************

TASK [debug] **************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_var3": "Hello world!"
}
```

Comment: I get the platform variable as a prompt on the localhost set of task and then use that same variable on the target set of tasks using the hostvars. I might not have explained it correctly, but it certainly works. :)